# Flyway: execute a single oracle sql file

Tags: flyway

In postgres, I can execute a single .sql file using `sqlMigrationSuffixes`.
But, I can't use the same option for oracle. The only way to do it in oracle is to create a different folder and put that single file in that folder. Not exactly my preference.
Is there another option for oracle that allows execution of a single .sql file ?

Additional Details:

OS: CENTOS 7

flyway.conf

```
flyway.url=${flyway:url}
flyway.user=${flyway:user}
flyway.password=${flyway:password}
flyway.schemas=${flyway:schemas}
flyway.locations=${flyway:locations}
flyway.sqlMigrationSuffixes=${flyway:sqlMigrationSuffixes}
```

Running from command line

```
flyway \
-url=... \
-user=... \
-password=... \
-schemas=... \
-locations=filesystem:oracle_sql \
-sqlMigrationSuffixes="Create_ro.sql" \
-placeholders.tableName=... \
-placeholders.roleName=... \
migrate
```

File structure

```
flyway
  |-conf
      |-flyway.conf
  |-oracle_sql
      |-R__create_ro.sql
      |-R__create_rw.sql
      |-R__create_user.sql
  |-pg_sql
      |-R__create_ro.sql
      |-R__create_rw.sql
      |-R__create_user.sql
```

The above only works for postgres. In order to be able to execute a single .sql file in oracle, I had to get rid of the sqlMigrationSuffixes and schemas, create a new config for oracle because of this then put each oracle .sql file in its own directory.

Below works. Not my preference, but works.

flyway.conf

```
flyway.url=${flyway:url}
flyway.user=${flyway:user}
flyway.password=${flyway:password}
flyway.locations=${flyway:locations}
```

File Structure

```
flyway
  |-conf
      |-oracle.conf
      |-postgres.conf
  |-oracle_sql
      |-create_ro
         |-R__create_ro.sql
      |-create_rw
         |-R__create_rw.sql
      |-create_user
         |-R__create_user.sql
  |-pg_sql
      |-R__create_ro.sql
      |-R__create_rw.sql
      |-R__create_user.sql
```

Comment: Flyway's script discovery and execution process doesn't change between databases. Can you provide more detail about what you've tried? Like your Flyway configuration, file system set up and so on.

Comment: @Mikiel, I added more details to my question. Hope this helps